# Get image width for a styled image in module

Tags: 7, media

In hook_node_load I need to get the width and height of a styled image, for a given fid.

The image style has only height effect and the width is scaled and calculated by Drupal, so using image_styles() is of no use.

My code so far is like this:

```
  $field_image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image', LANGUAGE_NONE);
  $img_uri = file_load($field_image[0]['fid']);
  $img_url = image_style_url('mystyle', $img_uri->uri);
  $img_info = image_get_info ($img_url);
```

$img_info gives me FALSE instead of the info. How to get the width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!image.inc/function/image_get_info/7), you just need `image_style_path` instead of `image_style_url`

and finally

```
 $field_image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image', LANGUAGE_NONE);
 $img_uri = file_load($field_image[0]['fid']);
 $img_url = image_style_path('mystyle', $img_uri->uri);
$img_info = image_get_info ($img_url);
```

Comment: This finally worked for me (with two additional steps):   $img_uri = file_load($field_image[0]['fid']);
  $img_style_uri = image_style_path('mystyle', $img_uri->uri);
  $img_url = file_create_url($img_style_uri);
  $img_server_path = drupal_realpath($img_style_uri);
  $img_info = image_get_info ($img_server_path); --- Besides, for this to work, the styled image must already be created (displayed at least once)